# Data Filtering from return of HTTP call - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, http-get, angular-filters

I want my application to display only 9 specific projects from a host of projects from a web service. 
At the minute, my app is working with test data I created myself in the project.service.http.ts class.

Instead of creating an observable of fake data, how do I use that so I can use my HTTP Get from web service as the observable?

Thanks in advance!

Output as of now
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My Code:
project.service.http.ts:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ProjectServiceHttp extends ProjectService {

        //variables
        baseUrl = "...";

            static projectIds: string[] = ["","","","","",""
                                    ,"", "",""];

//mock data BELOW
                                    data: Project[] = [
                                        {
                                          description: 'toto',
                                          href: 'aze',
                                          id: 'qqq',
                                          name: 'project_1',
                                          parentProjectId: '200'
                                        },
                                        {
                                          description: 'toto',
                                          href: 'aze',
                                          id: 'aaa',
                                          name: 'project_2',
                                          parentProjectId: '200'
                                        },
                                        {
                                          description: 'toto',
                                          href: 'aze',
                                          id: 'www',
                                          name: 'project_3',
                                          parentProjectId: '200'
                                        },
                                        {
                                          description: 'toto',
                                          href: 'aze',
                                          id: 'ggg',
                                          name: 'project_4',
                                          parentProjectId: '200'
                                        }
                                      ];


            //constructor
           constructor(private http: Http) {
                super();
            }

        //methods
//this method currently works and returns an observable of the mock data created above. However i want it to use the data from the HTTP get, like the method below..
        fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
            return Observable.of(this.data);
          }

        //method below to get the data from the web service 
        //not working yet??
     /* fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]>{
        console.log("reached service method");    
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
          .map(response => response.json());
        }  */

    }
```

project.viewer.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'project-viewer',
    templateUrl: './project-viewer.html',  
    styleUrls: ['./project-viewer.css']
})


export class ProjectViewerComponent  {
    name = 'ProjectViewerComponent';
    projects: Project[] = [];

    static testIds: string[] = ['qqq', 'aaa'];

    static projectIds: string[] = ["",""
    ,"","","",""
    ,"", "",""];

    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;

      constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
          this.projects = response.filter(elements => {
            return ProjectViewerComponent.testIds.includes(elements.id);
          });
        })
      }

//attempt method from earlier version
    /* private fetchProjects() {
        this.service
            .fetchProjects()
            .subscribe(response =>{
              this.projects = response['project']
              .filter(project => { return  ['', '','','','',''
              ,'','',''].indexOf(project.id) !== -1})
              console.log(response);
              console.log(this.projects);
            },
            errors=>{
               console.log(errors);
            });
    } */


}
```

project-viewer.html:

```
<h3>Projects </h3>
<div >
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let project of projects" class="col-1-4">
            <li class ="module project" >
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{project.name}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I answered your question in the first post. You already have your own service method ! I just had to use a fake one to simulate your backend that I could not reproduce for the original issue...
See the edited response in the first post

Comment: In the previous question you already have a fetchProjects() method that use Obrervable to get data from "dev-teamcity:8090/guestAuth/app/rest/projects". Just use that one.

Comment: @lingthe thank you! fixed it by changing my constructor in the project.viewer.compont.ts to :      constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
          this.projects = response['project'].filter(elements => {
            // BaseComponent was my class. Use yours.
            return ProjectViewerComponent.projectIds.includes(elements.id);
          });
        })
      }

Answer (score 0):

Modify the return of `fetchProjects()` after it is subscribed in `project.viewer.component.ts` to this,

```
return ProjectViewerComponent.projectIds.indexOf(elements.id !== -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i Understand exactly you want to filter the response form the API with your Array .. if so ..try something like:

```
    static projectIds: string[] = ["TotalMobileAnalyseInsights","TotalMobileMendel"
        ,"TotalMobileSlam","TotalMobileServer","TotalMobileWebAdmin","TotalMobileForAndroid"
        ,"TotalMobileForWindows", "TotalMobileForWindowsUniversal","TotalMobileForIOS"];




fetchProjects(): Promise<Project[]> {
          return  this.http<Project[]>.get('APIURL').map((resp)=>{

         return resp.filter(xx=> this.projectIds.id.indexOf(xx)>-1);
                }).toPromise();
          }
```

Hope it helps you!